# Why does an empty node.js script consume more and more RAM?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

Running this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log(process.memoryUsage());
}, 1000);
```

shows memory usage constantly growing:

```
{ rss: 9076736, heapTotal: 6131200, heapUsed: 2052352 }
... some time later
{ rss: 10960896, heapTotal: 6131200, heapUsed: 2939096 }
... some time later
{ rss: 11177984, heapTotal: 6131200, heapUsed: 3141576 }
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program isn't *empty*, it's running a timer, checking memory usage, and writing to the console once a second.  That causes objects to be created in the heap and until garbage collection runs your heap usage will keep increasing.

If you let it go you should eventually see `heapUsed` go back down each time garbage collection is triggered.

Comment: I've added `global.gc()` in each loop and started node with `--nouse-idle-notification --expose-gc` - did not fix the issue. Why is that?

Comment: @Fluffy I just tried that and making that change did keep `heapUsed` basically flat.

Comment: v8 is also doing quite a bit of work to try to optimize/recompile your code, and node's code, but as @JohnnyHK says, it will eventually flatten, or oscillate around a mostly flat line.